# Consultando cidades sem repetição e com "WHERE" diferente

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, query

Ao tentar resolver uma questão de banco da plataforma [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-3/problem) não consegui entender a resposta após ter encontrado na ala de discussão.

A questão diz:

> Query a list of CITY names from STATION with even ID numbers only. You may print the results in any order, but must exclude duplicates from your answer.
>
> > Faça uma consulta dos **nomes** das cidades na tabela **STATION** com apenas números ID de identificação. Você pode mostrar o resultado em qualquer ordem, mas exclua as respostas duplicadas.

---

> Descrição da tabela STATION
>
> > [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

A resposta marcada como certa seria

```
SELECT DISTINCT city FROM station WHERE (id % 2) = 0;
```

Minha dúvida é sobre o `WHERE (id % 2 ) = 0`, eu não entendi a resposta, a princípio somente o `DISTINCT` resolve a questão, alguém pode explicar?

Tem outra forma de fazer em MySQL?

Comment: Erro de tradução: "with even ID" se traduz para "com ID par". Sua tradução ignorou esse uso do `even`, que é contraposto ao `odd` (ímpar)

Comment: Se tivesse even number a tradução teria sido feita corretamente, agradeço pela observação @JeffersonQuesado =) eu passei batido =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Houve um erro de tradução ali. Ele quer resultados distintos que tenham ID não ímpar. Para descobrir se um inteiro é par, o resto da divisão por 2 deve ser zero. Pode representar em SQL dessa maneira:

```
inteiro % 2 = 0
```

Assim, a query fica desse jeito:

```
-- Weather Observation Station 3
-- Query a list of CITY names from STATION with even ID numbers only. You may print the results in any order, but must exclude duplicates from your answer.
-- https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-3/problem

SELECT DISTINCT City
FROM Station
WHERE Id % 2 = 0;
```

(tenho um repositório no GitHub com algumas soluções da track de SQL do HackerRank, [**se quiser dar uma olhada e contribuir**](https://github.com/vnbrs/hackerrank-sql), fique a vontade)